# For convertir lista a diccionario (Dudas)

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, diccionarios

Tengo una duda con el siguiente código en la linea donde se encuentra el arrow "<-":

```
a = {}
b = ["a","b","c"]
c = ["10","20","30"]

for i in range(len(b)):
    a[b[i]] = c[i] # <- 

print(a)
```

Realmente si alguien me puede explicar parte por parte por qué `a[b[i]]] = c[i]`

Gracias, soy principiante :)

Comment: Cada elemento de un diccionario es un par `[llave]:[valor]`. Para agregar, o actualizar elementos, se puede usar la notación: `diccionario[llave] = valor`. [Leer más](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

funciona de esta manera

```
a = {} # Diccionario vacío
b = ["a", "b", "c"] # esta lista posee 3 valores 
c = ["10", "20", "30"] # esta lista posee 3 valores


for i in range(len(b)): # el valor de i se va iterando, empieza en 0 y termina en 2
   
"""cuando i sea 0 el valor de b[i] será a y el valor de c[i] será 10, y así sucesivamente"""

    a[b[i]] = c[i] """la manera de crear un elemento en un diccionario es 
    Diccionario[clave] = valor"""
```

Comment: Esta era la respuesta que necesitaba leer, ya que no entendia la iteración de "i" y sus asignaciones para "b" y "c". Muchas gracias Milfuegos!

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo utilizando la funcion zip()

```
a = {}
b = ["a","b","c"]
c = ["10","20","30"]

for b,c in zip(b,c):
    a[b] = c

print(a)
```

o puedes hacerlo utilizando la funcion enumerate()

```
a = {}
b = ["a","b","c"]
c = ["10","20","30"]

for k,v in enumerate(b):
    a[v] = c[k]
print(a)
```

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias Bryro!